# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.  Absolutely new to DBA role, but I've worked with SQL and VS for a while.

I've installed the 2 aforementioned softwares on my home computer.  If I have VS2010 open and try to open the SQL Server database so I can make changes to something, I'm getting the error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Now, at work I can definitely have VS2010 open and edit stuff in my database, so I'm guessing there's a setting that allows you to do this?  Can anyone tell me where this setting is, and how to adjust it so that I don't have to exit VS2010 every time I need to write a new Stored Procedure in SQL Server?

Comment: See if anything on this post helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690119/visualstudio2010-debugging-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-i

Answer (score -2):

just make sure to close the designer window before hitting F5.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and welcome to the site. It might be even more helpful if you could describe why this works and how it would help.